# (C# Linq) Get items from a list when your ID is on another list

Tags: c#, linq

starting from this code:

```
class objeto
{
    public string codprod {get; set;}
    public int idprod {get; set;}
    public int idinvoice {get; set;}
}    

List<objeto> lista = new List<objeto>();
lista.Add(new objeto() {codprod = "a", idprod = 1, idinvoice = 1});
lista.Add(new objeto() {codprod = "a", idprod = 1, idinvoice = 2});
lista.Add(new objeto() {codprod = "a", idprod = 1, idinvoice = 3});
lista.Add(new objeto() {codprod = "b", idprod = 2, idinvoice = 1});
lista.Add(new objeto() {codprod = "c", idprod = 3, idinvoice = 1});

List<int> listaIDprod = new List<int>();
listaIDprod.Add(1);
listaIDprod.Add(2);
```

I need in "list" only the objects that have "idinvoice = 1" remain and that idprod is contained in idprod list.

Thanks

Comment: Starting from this code: objeto() will not compile

Comment: "I need in "list" only the objects that have "idinvoice = 1" remain and that idprod is contained in idprod list." And what is your problem in doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
var result = lista.Where(foo => foo.idinvoice == 1 && 
                                listaIDprod.Contains(foo.idprod)).ToList();
```

Please look into your code, before putting on SO. `class objeto()` should be `class objeto`.

Also, please choose sensible names for your classes and objects.

Comment: You should mention about syntax: `class objeto()` in the question.

Comment: Works fine.thanks a lot.